# How can I install python2.7 in the windows sandbox?

Tags: python-2.7, redistributable, windows-sandbox

The installer always fails in the windows sandbox because it can't install the Visual C++ Redistributable: `An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC90.CRT,version="9.0.30729.1"` I tried to

Unfortunately I have a piece of software that depends on python2.7. Is there any way to get python2.7 to run in the sandbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More recent versions of the windows sandbox don't expose this behaviour, so it looks like this was a bug inside the sandbox.